# Send csv file data to sqlite table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Model.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    Tag_name = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I need to create an API for onboarding the data in the csv into the tables.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your CSV format. As your model has a many to many field in it, you should define CSV in such a way that you can add as many "many to many fields" as you want. Lets suppose your CSV has following format.

```
name        | type
Question 1  | question
Tag 11      | tag
Tag 12      | tag
Tag 13      | tag
Question 2  | question
Tag 21      | tag
Tag 22      | tag
Tag 23      | tag
Tag 24      | tag
```

For this type of format, you can write your code like this

```
csv_rows = # write code to get CSV rows here
q_obj = None
for row in csv_rows:
    if row[1] == 'question':
       q_obj = Question.objects.create(name=row[0])
    elif row[1] == 'tag':
       if q_obj:
          tag_obj = Tag.objects.create(name=row[0])
          q_obj.Tag_name.add(tag_obj)
```

This format and code will handle any number of tags for a question